# Array not added to object in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to combine two arrays from MongoDB: an array of contact objects and an array of appointments.

My current solution is to query all contacts and appointments, loop over each array, compare the email and if they match, add each appointment to its corresponding contact.

```
    var contacts, appointments;
    Contact.find(query, function(err, result1) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
            contacts  = result1;

            Appointment.find({isArchived : false}, function(err, result2) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {

                    appointments = result2;
                    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length;i++) {
                        contacts[i]["appointments"] = [];
                        for (var j=0; j<appointments.length;j++) {
                            if (contacts[i].email === appointments[j].owner) {                                    
                                contacts[i].appointments.push(appointments[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    res.send(contacts);

                }                    
            });
        }            
    });
```

Contacts:

```js
[{
  email: "example1@example1.com"
}, {
  email: "example2@example2.com"
}]

[{
  email: "example1@example1.com",
  start: "2015-01-01",
  end: "2015-02-01"
}, {
  email: "example1@example1.com",
  start: "2015-02-01",
  end: "2015-03-01"
}]

// Desired output
[{
  email: "example1@example1.com",
  appointments: [{
    email: "example1@example1.com",
    start: "2015-01-01",
    end: "2015-02-01"
  }, {
    email: "example1@example1.com",
    start: "2015-02-01",
    end: "2015-03-01"
  }]
}, {
  email: "example2@example2.com",
  appointments: []
}]
```

I know it's a mess, and I'm also unable to append the appointment array to each contact. I can only assign values to existing object keys.

So it's really two questions: 1) Why can't I append the array to an existing contact, 2) what is a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot extend Mongoose results directly. For that to work, you must call .toObject() on the object you wish to extend.

I would love to have suggestions for a cleaner solution, preferrably one that only involves one mongodb call, and no manual array operations.